# Does rc.local crash?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, rc

I am using rc.local to run a python script on boot up on a raspberry pi and it almost always runs without an issue but on occasion, it seems like it might be crashing. Can a script run in rc.local crash with no error in the code? Would it be better to use systemd instead?

Comment: Do you think the dinner I had yesterday was rotten? What you recommend me to eat today? ;-P Without you entering into specifics, we cannot really help you.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The script is a client program that connects to a server and sends images but it is disconnecting on occasion and I'm fairly certain the code doesn't have any errors and should be able to handle any errors. So I am wondering if rc.local is known to stop programs I don't know how to get anymore information than that.

Comment: No, `rc.local` does not stop programs willy nilly. Enable debugging in your program, look at logs, run it outside of `rc.local` and investigate what's happening.

Comment: Why would you make an image transfer part of your boot process??

Comment: @GerardH.Pille He's probably starting it as a daemon thingy. What I'm most interested in is why he thinks his program is error free.

Answer (score 0):

`rc.local` doesn't do much besides run your code.

A benefit to `systemd` is that it has an option to restart your code if it crashes, which `rc.local` does not.

So if you can't prevent your code from crashing in the same way again, perhaps you can design so that it at least has a chance of working properly if it is restarted after such a crash.